# get height and width image before loading in html

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have origin width and height for image.i want to find out how image scale in the div according to the origin image size and div size.for example image size is 400*1120 and div size is 500*800.in this case what is the image size after loading in that div.this is css code for image:

```
img{
position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please describe your question more clearly.

Comment: before image loaded i send an ajax and get origin height and width of image.so i want to display thumbnail for image in width and height of origin image .when image size is greater that div size the image scale according to the div size.i want to find out how image scale when image size larger than div size

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying is a scale to fit without distorting the image, just remove the position, left, top and transform properties from the image and apply them to your div container. The image should only have the max-width and max-height set to 100% and it will work.

```
#yourcontainer
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img
{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```